# Creating a database like metadata model in IGC using Open IGC Bundles

Tags: ibm-information-server

I am trying to create database like metamodel in IGC using Bundles which will be having Tables, Columns, Physical and logical models, Primary and Foreign Keys. How can I create relationship with Key and Columns using custom assets like we have existing one in IGC?

Answer (score 1):

IGC allows you to extend the Catalog and introduce new types of Assets, where you can manage their structure and display.  The management of such new Assets is via the supported IGC REST, and you may use the IGC REST Explorer to initially test and publish bundles and post details of such Assets.  The default URL for the IGC REST Explorer is:  https://YOURSERVER:9443/ibm/iis/igc-rest-explorer/

If you expand the section Bundles - you can use the action: post /bundles/ to create a new set of Assets - Terminal Applications.  Use the attached bundle archive.
Additionally - you can use the action: post /bundles/assets to create the instances of such Assets.  Copy the contents of the attached file.